# GoogleAPIClient is null even when logged in successfully

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I have successfully added Google authentication in android app. I am able to login properly without any error. But when i try to logout GoogleApiClient is giving me null so that i am failing to logout successfully. I tried so many answers here but nothing worked for me. Below is the code I entered in my MainActivity.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(ApplicationPreferences.get().isFirstTimeUser()) {
                GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestScopes(new Scope(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY))
                        .requestServerAuthCode(Constants.SERVER_CLIENT_ID, true)
                        .requestEmail()
                        .build();

                signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
                signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
                signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        switch (view.getId()) {
                            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                                signIn();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                signInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
                // options specified by gso.
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .enableAutoManage(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this)
                        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(MainActivity.this)
                        .build();
           mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            } else {
                loadMainActivity();
            }
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Below is my signOut method as specified by [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect) but i failed to understand their statement **You must confirm that GoogleApiClient.onConnected has been called before you call signOut.** Need some idea what I am doing wrong here.

```
if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
    {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {

                        ApplicationPreferences.get().clearAll();
                        Intent intent = getIntent();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
    }
```

My OnStart()

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        showProgressDialog();
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                hideProgressDialog();
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did the `GoogleApiClient`'s callback method being called to signal that the connection to the API service has succeeded?

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla No it is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

The error, if you say callbacks are not being called, might just be the sign that you may not have connected first. I imagine you have implemented the callbacks and they are not being called?

In any case, to "handle" the error situation, you may want to check if the `GoogleApiClient` is connected.. like this:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
    {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {

                        ApplicationPreferences.get().clearAll();
                        Intent intent = getIntent();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
    }
else{
   Log.w("SomeTag", "It looks like GoogleApiClient is not connected");
}
```

But I do think you need to check if there are any errors (for instance does `onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result)` get called instead? What error do you see?

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ismaelMakitla I made some changes to my code. GoogleAPIClient is getting connected. Now OnStart GoogleAPI client is null.

Comment: Please include your code - the onCreate as well as the onStart - it will help to see at what stage you connect your apiClient.

Comment: Why do you have the `ApiClient` in `onStart` to do `silentSignIn`? This should happen in the callback that indicates that the `GoogleApiClient` has connected - the `onStart` is the activity's lifecycle method and does not really indicate anything regarding your `GoogleApiClient` status. As a test, please move the code from `onStart` to the `onConnected` callback.

Comment: I followed https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java#L143-L153"

Comment: I see, but it seems you did not implement the `onCreate` the way the sample code suggests...which has to do with how you initialize the googleApiClient.